# Python Django webpage works manually but domain gives 404 error on shared host

Tags: python, django, shared-hosting

I am using justhost (shared hosting) to test out a python django webpage on my subdomain dev.domain_name.com

I used the following tutorial: http://flailingmonkey.com/install-django-justhost/ to get the below output.

Command to get the below: python mysite.fcgi

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE"><title>Welcome to Django</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; }
    h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
    h2 span { font-size:80%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
    h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
    table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
    tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    thead th {
      padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left;
      font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    tbody th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    #summary { background: #e0ebff; }
    #summary h2 { font-weight: normal; color: #666; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; }
    #instructions { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #summary table { border:none; background:transparent; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>It worked!</h1>
  <h2>Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.</h2>
</div>

<div id="instructions">
  <p>
    Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Next, start your first app by running <code>python manage.py startapp [app_label]</code>.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p>
    You're seeing this message because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in your Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!
  </p>
</div>
</body></html>


Tech Stack:
Python 2.7.2
flup 1.0.2
django 1.8.7

**My subdomain dev.domain_name.com returns:**
Not Found The requested URL /mysite.fcgi/ was not found on this server.

Below is .htaccess & mysite.fcgi

[~/public_html/subdomaindirectory]# vi mysite.fcgi
#!/home2/findity/python/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/findity1/python")

path = '/home2/findity1/public_html/findityaardev/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)

print(sys.path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")


.htaccess file:
[~/public_html/subdomaindirectory]# vi .htaccess

AddHandler fcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Notes: I added .fcgi apache handler from cpanel which brought me from 500 internal server error to 404. It looks like it works manually based on the command however I cannot see it out my subdomain. Do let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: "It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page." - Thats the default page you get when you first start django, what isn't working?

Comment: It isnt working on the domain (dev.domain_name.com), I get a 404 error Not Found The requested URL /mysite.fcgi/ was not found on this server. When I run it manually on the server "python mysite.fcgi" it shows the success output including these:
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about the folder structure?

Comment: Level 1: root for subdomain: /home2/username/public_html/subdomain/
Level 2: files & folders under subdomain root: /home2/username/public_html/subdomain/:
mysite.fcgi
.htaccess
mysite/
Level 3: files & folders under mysite: /home2/username/public_html/subdomain/mysite:
manage.py
Level 4: /home2/username/public_html/subdomain/mysite/mysite:
 __init__.py    settings.py  settings.pyc  urls.py  urls.pyc  wsgi.py  wsgi.pyc

Answer (score 0):

First look at the note in the [Django 1.8 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/):

> since version 1.7:
>   FastCGI support is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.

So possibly another method would be preferred.

I note that your `mysite.fcgi` has a print statement. Remove it, I don't think fastcgi processes have access to stdout ([it goes to the server instead](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html#S1)). This could be causing problems.

If that does not fix the problem, the first thing is to try and identify where the error. I think it is most likely occurring in one of the following places:

- The redirect is not working.
- Or Apache cannot find `mysite.fcgi`.
- Or the mysite.fcgi invokes Django which is returning 404.
- Or maybe Django is working, but using a view that is returning 404.

Look in the Apache `error.log` file, see if this overs any clues as to which one of these is the problem area.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I removed the comment but no difference, I currently get a [an error occurred while processing this directive] on my url. Unfortunately, since the apache settings and logs are not accessible by me due to shared hosting. I am using 1.8.7 django which has the fastcgi libraries, also the running the command python mysite.fcgi on the shared hosting gives the above output, so it is able to identify fastcgi. I believe it is my .htaccess file which might be the issue (especially the path).

Answer (score 0):

Next are my .htaccess and django.fcgi files.
These files are working properly in JustHost.
I am currently running 3 Django powered websites in Justhost with this configuration.

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am using a minimalistic .fcgi file (django.fcgi in my case)

```
#!/home/.../venv/bin/python
# DO NOT USE SOMETHING LIKE THIS #!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/.../django_project_directory")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "my_project_name.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

EDIT:
I am using Django 1.8.x. I don't have currently any project with Django 1.9.x

Comment: Thanks ePi272314 for responding.

My site still shows the following error:
[an error occurred while processing this directive]

My file .htaccess:
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]


My file mysite.fcgi:

import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/findity1/public_html/findityaardev/mysite")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")

Is my folder structure or something else incorrect?

Comment: Hola.
Your .htaccess file looks fine.

Comment: Regardless the mysite.fcgi file:
* Ensure it is executable "chmod +x mysite.fcgi"
* You are missing the first line of my example: "#!absolute_path_to_python_executable".
* But if you are using virtual environments then indicate the path to the python in that virtual environment.
* The path in "sys.path.insert" is to your django project directory not to your public_html/mysite directory. I am assuming that you don't have your django project in your public_html because is not secure.

Comment: Other possible issues:
* You must install flup: Activate you virtual environment and "pip install flup==1.0.2".
* Remember to change ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings file: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", ".mysite.com",].
* If you are using a linux server but you use windows to generate the files .htaccess and fcgi sometimes you can have issues. Use "dos2unix .htaccess" and "dos2unix mysite.fcgi".